# BLE-serial module barebone (just need TX/RX and AT interrupt)

Tags: serial, bluetooth

I want to add to my project, a BLE module; althought I am totally confused about which one should I get.

I did check most of the common chip available; and I do not get exactly if I can just use the chip as is, or if it require extras (crystal, resistors and such). The nordic module for example; is not just the Nordic chip, but include a lot of other components, looking at the picture.

I just need TX, RX and the interrupt to set the AT commands on the chip; and obviously the power and GND lines; most of the BLE module on the market, have also their own Cortex mounted in the package, which to me would be basically wasted.

Could you point me to what kind of chip should I look for? Ideally I want something that is ready to be used; once I connect the TX-RX, GND, PWR and interrupt for AT command from the chip.

And to be clear, I am not asking what is better; this is not based on personal opinions; I did state the usage and what I am looking for; so the question is totally legit and not opinion based. Thanks

Comment: Those modules are exactly what you want.

Comment: So any of them would fit for my needs? Isn't possible to use just a chip? Since I am making my own PCB, I would like the simplest solution available,  and also the one that allow me to save as much space as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A module like [this](http://www.tinyosshop.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=705) one are actually two parts.

[image]

The Module with some RF related parts, a crystal/oscillator, board antenna, and a Breakout board. The boards are mostly just for user interaction. Status Leds, Voltage Regulator, Reverse Voltage Protection, And level translation. Most of the modules are 3.3V only, while the target market for these are hobbyists using 5V Arduinos.

You could definitely make your own board to mount the module on assuming you provide 3.3V power directly. A board like that though, already provides a regulator, and has the bare minimum pinout for your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! Would be possible to remove also the rest of the components, minus the antenna? I am going for the smallest footprint possible; or there is no way to get below the module mounted on this breakout board?

Comment: You could make a double sided board if you needed to.

Comment: Good point; I guess why should I make it harder, when I can use the module with the basics alrady taken care of? Thanks!